# "Go to implementation" keymap works for a different purpose when internal actions is on

Tags: intellij-idea

In order to narrow line height for project view, I enable internal actions. However default go to implementation keymap "Ctrl+Alt+Click" opens an Intellij editor implementation class property popup.

[Popup example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hM91G.png)

Since I'm used to this keymap for "Go to implementation" I want to keep it. But I couldn't find a way to disable other behavior.

How can I disable it? Or is there a way to change keymap for it?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove a shortcut in the settings.

Navigate to *File | Settings | Keymap Main Menu | Tools | Internal Actions | UI | UI Inspector*, right-click on the item and select *Remove Ctrl+Alt+Click*.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot ! I didn't know that I navigate keymaps from there.